# How to perform undo in Recoil's history example

Tags: recoiljs

https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects/#history-example

In the link above, the documentation shows an example for keeping track a history of state changes. Each state has an `undo` method that would revert to the previous state.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to actually access the `undo` method. Printing out the value of the atom doesn't have any reference to history or undo. I also have my atom persisting to local storage which, again, has nothing extra, as I would expect.

Comment: If you mean [this example](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/blob/925948b0ec88a0a0c9c3ad3e7f510dfbbb182bb9/docs/docs/guides/atom-effects.md#history-example), then it would be accessed by `history.at(index)?.undo()`

Comment: @jsejcksn that doesn't feel like a great solution. As your state grows, knowing the exact index isn't a trivial task.